# Review my first jQuery slider plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

This is my first jQuery plugin.  It is a simple slider that requires very little mark up in html.  It works for my purposes but I am not a jQuery expert and I am wondering if there are mistakes or shortcuts that I took in its creation.

Thank you for taking a look at the plugin!

## The HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.st-slider').stSlider();
    });
</script>

<div id="feature-slider" class="st-slider">
      <ul>
           <li data-collection-name="Collection 1"><a href="#"><img src="images/slide1.jpg"></a></li>
           <li data-collection-name="Collection 2"><a href="#"><img src="images/slide2.jpg"></a></li>
           <li data-collection-name="Collection 3"><a href="#"><img src="images/slide3.jpg"></a></li>
           <li data-collection-name="Collection 4"><a href="#"><img src="images/slide4.jpg"></a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

## The CSS

```
.st-slider {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 685px;
    height: 412px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
.st-slider ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.st-slider ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.st-slider .st-slider-caption {
    background: rgba(215,204,186,0.8);
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .3em;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    top: 280px;
    width: 685px;
}
.st-slider .st-slider-caption span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 685px;
}
.st-slider .st-slider-nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 229px;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 62px;
    width: 100%;
}
.st-slider .st-slider-nav div {
    background: url('../images/st-slider-nav.png');
    width: 30px;
    height: 62px;   
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.st-slider .st-slider-nav .next {
    background-position: -30px 0;
    left: 655px;
}   
.st-slider .st-slider-nav .prev:hover {
    background-position: -60px 0;   
}
.st-slider .st-slider-nav .next:hover {
    background-position: -90px 0;   
} 
.st-slider-go-to-nav {
    display: block;
    margin-top: -55px;
    padding-top: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
}
.st-slider-go-to-nav {
    list-style: none;
}
.st-slider-go-to-nav li {
    padding: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
}
.st-slider-go-to-nav li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
.st-slider-go-to-nav li a {
    padding: 5px 8px;
    color: #aaa;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.st-slider-go-to-nav li a:hover, .st-slider-go-to-nav li.current a {
    color: #666;
    background: #eee;
}
```

## The jQuery

```
(function( $ ) {

$.fn.stSlider = function() {


    var sliderContainer = $(this),
        slidePane       = sliderContainer.find('ul'),
        cloneFirst      = slidePane.find('li:first-child').clone(),
        cloneLast       = slidePane.find('li:last-child').clone();

    cloneFirst.attr('data-clone', 'last').appendTo(slidePane);
    cloneLast.attr('data-clone', 'first').prependTo(slidePane);


    var slides = slidePane.find('li');

    var slideWidth     = $(this).width(),
        negSlideWidth  = 0 - slideWidth,
        slidesArray    = $.makeArray(slides),
        slidePaneWidth = ( slidesArray.length  * slideWidth );

    // Build slider controls
    var captionHolderDiv = $('<div class="st-slider-caption"></div>'),
        captionDiv       = $('<span></span> '),
        navDiv           = $('<div class="st-slider-nav"></div>'),
        prevDiv          = $('<div class="prev"></div>'),
        nextDiv          = $('<div class="next"></div>'),
        goToNav          = $('<ul class="st-slider-go-to-nav"></ul>');

    // Insert slider controls into DOM
    slidePane.after(captionHolderDiv);
    captionDiv.appendTo(captionHolderDiv);
    captionHolderDiv.after(navDiv);
    prevDiv.appendTo(navDiv);
    nextDiv.appendTo(navDiv);
    sliderContainer.after(goToNav);

    // Build and insert each slide number link
    for(var i = 0; i < slidesArray.length - 2; i++) {
        var count = i + 1;
        var goToNavItem = $('<li id="' + count + '"><a>' + count + '</a></li>');

        goToNavItem.appendTo(goToNav);

        if ( count ==  1 ) {
            goToNavItem.addClass('current');
        }
    }

    var slideCaptionHolder = sliderContainer.find('.st-slider-caption span'),
        slideCaption       = sliderContainer.find('li:nth-child(2)').data('collection-name'),
        goToArray          = $('.st-slider-go-to-nav li');

    slidePane.width(slidePaneWidth);
    slides.addClass('st-slider-slide');
    slidePane.animate({left: negSlideWidth}, 0);

    slideCaptionHolder.html(slideCaption);


    function slide(direction, location) {

        var x            = parseInt(slidePane.css('left'), 10),
            y            = Math.abs(x),
            i            = 0,
            theSlide     = slides.eq(i),
            slideCaption = theSlide.data('collection-name'),
            slideClone   = theSlide.data('clone'),
            lastPosition = 0 - slidePaneWidth + (slideWidth * 2);

        if ( direction == 'null' ) { }

        else if (direction == 'prev') {

            i = (y / slideWidth) -1;
            i = i % slidesArray.length;

            theSlide     = slides.eq(i);
            slideCaption = theSlide.data('collection-name');
            slideClone   = theSlide.data('clone');

            slidePane.animate({left: parseInt(slidePane.css('left'), 10) + slideWidth}, 600);

            slideCaptionHolder.fadeOut(300, function() {
                $(this).html(slideCaption);
                $(this).fadeIn(300, function(){
                    if ( slideClone && slideClone == 'first' ) {
                        slidePane.animate({left: lastPosition}, 0);
                    }
                });
            });

            goToArray.removeClass('current');

            if ( slideClone == 'last') {
                goToArray.eq(slidesArray.length - 2).addClass('current');
            } else {
                goToArray.eq(i - 1).addClass('current');
            }

        }

        else {

            i = (y / slideWidth) +1;
            i = i % slidesArray.length;

            theSlide     = slides.eq(i);
            slideCaption = theSlide.data('collection-name');
            slideClone   = theSlide.data('clone');

            slidePane.animate({left: parseInt(slidePane.css('left'), 10) - slideWidth }, 600);

            slideCaptionHolder.fadeOut(300, function() {
                $(this).html(slideCaption);
                $(this).fadeIn(300, function(){
                    if ( slideClone && slideClone == 'last' ) {
                        slidePane.animate({left: negSlideWidth }, 0);
                    }
                });
            });

            goToArray.removeClass('current');

            if ( slideClone == 'last') {
                goToArray.eq(0).addClass('current');
            } else {
                goToArray.eq(i - 1).addClass('current');
            }
        }


        if ( location ) {

            i = location;

            theSlide        = slides.eq(i);
            slideCaption = theSlide.data('collection-name');
            slideClone   = theSlide.data('clone');

            slidePane.animate({left: 0 - (i * slideWidth) }, 600);

            slideCaptionHolder.fadeOut(300, function() {
                $(this).html(slideCaption);
                $(this).fadeIn(300, function(){
                    if ( slideClone && slideClone == 'last' ) {
                        slidePane.animate({left: negSlideWidth }, 0);
                    } else if ( slideClone && slideClone == 'first' ) {
                        slidePane.animate({left: lastPosition}, 0);
                    }
                });
            });
                goToArray.removeClass('current');
                goToArray.eq(i - 1).addClass('current');
        }

    }

    timer = setInterval(slide, 5000);


    sliderContainer.hover(function(){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }, function(){
        timer = setInterval(slide, 5000);
    });


    var slidePrev = sliderContainer.find('.prev'),
        slideNext = sliderContainer.find('.next');

    slidePrev.click(function(){
        slide('prev');
    });

    slideNext.click(function(){
        slide();
    });

    $('.st-slider-go-to-nav li a').click(function(){

        if ( $(this).parent().hasClass('current') ) {

        } else {
            var location = $(this).parent().attr('id');

            slide('null', location);

            clearInterval(timer);
            timer = setInterval(slide, 5000);
        }

    });
};

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems solid to me, only a few things my eye caught:

- you're using `$(this)` in multiple places, while your `sliderContainer` already holds that jQuery object. This object can be then reused instead of making jQuery convert DOM into jQuery several times
- instead of writing `cloneFirst.attr('data-clone', 'last').appendTo(slidePane);` it's advised to use jQuery's data() function to set data for DOM elements: `cloneFirst.data('clone', 'last').appendTo(slidePane);`

Comment: Wow! First of all, thank you so much for the feedback!

Second, thank you for the advice on using  `$(this)`.

As for using `.data()`, I tried that first but it did not seem to create the `data-collection-name` attribute in the html since it wasn't already there.  Perhaps I missed something?

Comment: interesting remark with regards to the data() function... if that didn't work, perhaps it would be wise to ask/report this to jQuery forums / bug tracker?

Comment: This plugin does not seem to work when multiple instaces of the function is called on `$(document).ready();`.  I am guessing I will need to loop through each function call to maintain the identity of the one that is being executed?  I am not sure.  It doesn't particularly matter for this project but it would be nice to have an idea if in the future I needed to expand to multiple instances.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot answer that question... I have  never done a jQuery plugin and I was merely reviewing the code for performance and best practices issues... perhaps you can try and ask on StackOverflow if you need to resolve the issue instead?